# Flask Security - Send confirmation email?

Tags: flask, flask-security

I am trying to create a flask boilerplate app and I am running into an error when I try to run a flask-script. I am getting an error that I don't fully understand, the code is broken up into several modules so it may be best to post the link to the repository. The two parts in the traceback that are my code are an import from the app and the creation of the security object.

The two files that are causing conflict are:

- `manage.py`
- `app/__init__.py`

What caused the problem is that I set several security variables to true:

```
SECURITY_REGISTERABLE = True
SECURITY_SEND_REGISTER_EMAIL = True
SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE = True
SECURITY_CONFIRM_URL = True
SECURITY_EMAIL_SENDER = 'some_email_account'
SECURITY_CONFIRM_LOGIN_WITHOUT_CONFIRMATION = False
SECURITY_TRACKABLE = True
SECURITY_CHANGEABLE = True
```

The project can be found here:
[github link](https://github.com/spitfiredd/flask-boilerplate)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import app, db, Role, user_datastore
  File "C:\Users\...\dev\flask-boilerplate\app\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    security = Security(app, user_datastore)
  File "C:\Users\...\dev\flask-boilerplate\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_security\core.py", line 469, in __init__
    self._state = self.init_app(app, datastore, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\dev\flask-boilerplate\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_security\core.py", line 507, in init_app
    app.register_blueprint(create_blueprint(state, __name__))
  File "C:\Users\...\dev\flask-boilerplate\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_security\views.py", line 383, in create_blueprint
    '<token>'),
  File "C:\Users\...\dev\flask-boilerplate\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_security\utils.py", line 249, in slash_url_suffix
    return url.endswith('/') and ('%s/' % suffix) or ('/%s' % suffix)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SECURITY_CONFIRM_URL` must be a string (i.e. `SECURITY_CONFIRM_URL='https://google.com`)